# Move a set of rows sperated by a blank line from a file to new file having a specific key

Tags: bash, shell

I have file containing lines as given below. I want to move a set of rows to a new file, if any line from set of rows contain key word SEDS2-TOP. each set of rows sperated by blank line.

```
0.00  600.00  2214.28   785.71 1.00000 SEDS1-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  2214.28   785.71 1.00000 SEDS1-TOP
0.00  600.00  1500.00     0.00 1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-TOP
0.00    0.00  600.00  1500.00  1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  1500.00     0.00 1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
```

Example the output file should have

```
0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-TOP
0.00    0.00  600.00  1500.00  1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  1500.00     0.00 1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
```

Comment: It is a good manner to provide the sample input and the expected output to clarify the requirement. It is also advised to include what you have tried to show your effort. BR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS="\n\n" } /SEDS2-TOP/' input.txt
0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-BOTTOM
0.00  600.00  2218.64   790.51 1.00000 SEDS1-TOP
0.00    0.00  600.00  1500.00  1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
0.00  600.00  1500.00     0.00 1.00000 WATER-BOTTOM

0.00  600.00  3446.97  1757.08 1.00000 SEDS2-TOP
```

The trick here is setting `RS` to two newlines, so that each blank line between groups denotes a new record, instead of the default of each line being one. Then it just prints out records containing that string.

If using GNU awk, consider using `/\<SEDS2-TOP\>/` for the regular expression to avoid matching things like `SEDS2-TOPPER` if that might be an issue with your data.

Comment: I want to move those rows from the original file, above code is copying.

Comment: I have tried  awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS="\n\n" "mv" } /SEDS2-TOP/'   input.txt, by inserting move command but its not worked

Comment: @rehman By move do you mean deleting those blocks from the original file?